# intellij idea incorrect processing of regex: "regular expression matches empty string"

Tags: intellij-idea

When regex contain simple `.*` is does not find anything.

Example from picture: we're taking whole line into capturing group, and in replacement just to prepend `a` to match.

What is this behavior? Is there some flag to turn off intellij-idea interpretation of my regexes? What is so wrong with empty string match in first place??? Also `.*` is greedy, so it can match empty string only if there is empty line, which there isn't. Switch "search in selection makes no difference".

[image: li]

Comment: Looks like a bug. Please report an issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: Your regex does not "contain simple `.*`", it is `^(.*)$`. Empty string matches do not seem to be very useful for replacements.

Comment: @xehpuk a) OK, but if you see the screenshot, there aren't empty string matches right? It does not match string `aa` for example. b) we have regex language. If it would be possible, I'd like idea to just just that grammar and leave out decision what is useful for me. For example, some idea version refuses to match end of line, which is very useful when you need to add smth at line end. Yes I can workaround it, but really, idea should not try to "fix" user regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround for this problem, you can use a regular expression like the following: `^(.*\n)`